# listbox and javascript to add items

Tags: asp.net, javascript, listbox

I've 2 asp listbox controls and an html input button, and using js i add items (previously loaded from DB) from listbox A to  B and it works fine, but when i submit the form, in the code behind the listbox B do not have the item i added accessible.

My idea was trying to save roundtrips to the server and make it in client side but looks like it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks you very much for you time!

**EDIT**

There's the code

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxOrgs" runat="server" Height="117px"  Width="502px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddItems2Listbox('lstBoxOrgs', 'lstBoxUserRelOrgs') "/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void AssignOrgs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem orgItem in lstBoxUserRelOrgs.Items)
    {
        //Update database here...
    }

    //Commit updates to DB
    cdc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The `onclick="AddItems2Listbox('lstBoxOrgs', 'lstBoxUserRelOrgs')`  is the javascript function that adds the items from lisbox A to listbox B.

Thanks

Comment: please add your code (or a simple case of it) and then it is much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options. First option is to keep track of what options were added in hidden variables and read that on the server.

The second option is to select all of the options when the page submits and use [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) to get the values of the options in the list.

You can not reference your select like you always do in the backend since the viewstate has no clue that options were added/removed.